# How to derive transform fourier for general expression of gaussian $e^{-\frac{ax^2}{2}}$ for $a>0$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to understand how to get general expression for fourier transform for $$\large f(x)=e^{-\frac{ax^2}{2}}$$

if $a=1$ I understand that I can calculate it through the fact that
$$ f'(x)=-xf(x)$$ $$ w \hat f(w) = -\hat f'(w)$$
and because $f$ and $\hat f$ solve the same differential equation they are same function that might different in scalar multiply. so we can get
$$\hat f(w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{w^2}{2}}$$
how do I get general form for $a>0$?

Comment: You can reduce the general case to the case $a=1$. For this do the substitution $u=\sqrt{a}x$ in the definition of the Fourier transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int e^{-itx} e^{-ax^{2}/2}dx=\frac1  {\sqrt a}\int e^{-ity/\sqrt a} e^{-y^{2}/2}dy$ by the substitution $y=\sqrt a x$. The integral here is the value of the FT in the case $a=1$ with $t$ changed to $\frac  t {\sqrt a}$.